# Checking if beautiful soup.find_all value is empty

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, null, beautifulsoup

Hello everybody once again, python noob here.
I am slowly progressing with my project, yet fixing one bug, caused another issue to come. Long story short:
I have

`for tempNext in soup3.find_all(title=re.compile("^Next Page -")):`

..loop that lets me find a href value. It works great, if the value exists. If NOT, it keeps reusing the same one from previous time. Sadly it's not as simple as resetting the value to `""` each time as this for loop is also within another loop.

JUST TO GET THE IDEA, this is how the snippet looks:

```
soup3 = make_soup('http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/' + link)
        while tempNumber < 4:
            for postScrape in soup3.find_all(id=re.compile("^td_post_")):
                post = ""
                post += postScrape.get_text(strip=True)
                postData += post + "\n"
                print(post)
            for tempNext in soup3.find_all(title=re.compile("^Next Page -")):
                tempNextPage = ""
                tempNextPage += (tempNext.get('href'))
                print(tempNextPage)
            soup3 = ""
            soup3 = make_soup('http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/' + tempNextPage)
            tempNumber += 1
        tempNumber = 1
    number += 1
    print(number)
    newUrl = "http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/" + nextPage
    soup = make_soup(newUrl)
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to check `for tempNext in soup3.find_all(title=re.compile("^Next Page -")):` value if it's empty, and if it is, just set `tempNextPage = ""` however for last couple hours I cannot figure it out.

If I just set it to empty value after loop is done, it no longer scrapes other pages.

Thank you for taking your time to read this question, any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare -or reset- `tempNextPage` variable outside `for` loop, and reassign the variable to new value -instead of appending new value to it- within the `for` loop. This way the value of `tempNextPage` would stay empty if `soup3.find_all()` didn't find any matching element and you can take action based on whether `tempNextPage` is empty :

```
while tempNumber < 4:
    tempNextPage = ""
    for postScrape in soup3.find_all(id=re.compile("^td_post_")):
        ....
    for tempNext in soup3.find_all(title=re.compile("^Next Page -")):
        tempNextPage = tempNext.get('href')
        print(tempNextPage)

    # process tempNextPage only if it is not empty
    if not tempNextPage:
        soup3 = make_soup('http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/' + tempNextPage)
        ....
    # do something else otherwise
    else :
        ....
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks a lot for looking through my cluster. It was actually enough to just reset it outside the FOR loop, yet if I added the check (If not) I would get error messages for soup3.find_all. However without it, it works fine, still would love to come up with a way to not have it in a massive nested loop, but will absolutelly work for now. Thank you!